# Orleans Architecture Design - Silo projects combined or separate?

Tags: orleans

There is an IoT data *collection* project, and an IoT data *processing* project.  They are separately developed and maintained.  However, it would be beneficial to share common grains between them in an Orleans silo (or silo cluster).  How would the architecture look in a self-hosted scenario - a monolithic silo with references to both projects for communication within the silo or two separate silos communicating externally?  If in a single silo, can a silo dynamically discover grain .dll's?

Comment: Note that if you go with monolithic silo, it becomes non trivial to deploy new versions of either one of the projects. Projects that should have been decoupled, but since they run in the same silo(s) you can't deploy a new version of one project without effecting the other (otherwise you might end up with two grains referencing the same entity)

Comment: Thanks shay, that makes sense to me too.  I'm still trying to understand how the silo hosts work, but decoupled does seem the right way to go for all the usual reasons.

Comment: check out feature #685 - https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/685 , it will make everything easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will probably be better answers, but until then:

There are some trade-offs. Performance-wise, it's better to spread all your grains (of all services) across the cluster. This way every grain communicates with other grains via Orleans infrastructure (I guess that's binary serialized messages through tcp), without any additional overhead. But when every service (or project) has it's own silo, you will need a gateway - HTTP listener maybe - in addition to Orleans. However, in the first example, your services become coupled. You cannot deploy a new version of a service, as long as there is a silo running an older version of it (otherwise, there might be 2 grains of the same entity). But if you shut down that silo, you are shutting down the rest of the services. This is a very non trivial issue.

> If in a single silo, can a silo dynamically discover grain .dll's

Not sure what you mean. When a silo boots up, it recursively searches for dlls inside it's folder, and if it finds grains, loads them.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's what I'm looking for.  The references to the grain implementations and interfaces in the sample projects threw me on that one.  So I'm guessing they are there just to get the .dlls into the bin directory?

Comment: In the early version of the sample projects they used a post-build script in the **grains project** to copy all the dll's from the grains bin directory into the **silo directory**. This way the silo project was completely decoupled from the grains project. I don't know about the newer versions of the sample projects, but I guess it makes sense to use project reference instead of a post-build script.